# Why will pop-ups be closed without permission? google Auth2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-oauth

Authentication often fails with the Google API, and I am in trouble because I can not identify the cause or the corrective action.
Please give me a professor.

**Phenomenon of failure**

With only one account signed in to your Google Account,
Attempting to log in again with Google Account with Auth2 authentication of Google API will result in a popup_closed_by_user error (user pop-up closed)
Authentication fails.

Often it occurs in Chrome, IE is less likely to occur.
However, if multiple accounts are already logged in to your Google Account,
The above authentication error does not occur and it is normally authenticated.

**Environment**

**OS**：Windows7(64bit)

**Chrome**: 66.0.3359.181

**IE**: 11.0.9600.18402

**※Browser's pop-up block is released**

**Google API**

Authentication of the gapi.auth2.authorize method fails.

Documentation I am following: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

The following parameters are specified.

```
gapi.auth2.authorize({
'client_id': clientId,
'scope': "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
'immediate': true
},
```

Comment: I've attempted to format your question and add relevant tags. Before without a programming language tag, people who don't know Javascript would have been encountering the issue, now it will be more targeted to people who program in Javascript + google authentication API's :-) Hopefully I didn't make any errors, it was hard to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

gapi.auth2. authorize() doesn't support the immediate:true parameter. If you want to try immediate mode, use  prompt:'none' instead. More detail at: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeconfig

Let me know if this fixed your bug or not.